# React useState is not updating when set method is called in an interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io, setinterval, react-usecallback

I have a websocket server that sends an object containing some hashes every 15 seconds. When the client receives a hash, I want to check with my current hash. If they differ, I want to make a call to an API to fetch new data.

The socket is working and sending the hash correctly. If the data updates on the server I get a different hash. My problem is that the hash variable I use to store the current hash is not updated correctly.

I have disabled the socket listening in my component, just to make sure that that is not the problem. Instead I have added a `setInterval` to mimik the socket update.

This is my code (socked code disabled but left as a comment):

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth, useSocket } from "../utils/hooks";

const Admin = () => {
    const [ questionLists, setQuestionLists ] = useState<QuestionListModel[]>([]); 
    const { user } = useAuth();
    const { socket } = useSocket();
    const [ hash, setHash ] = useState<Hash>({questionList: ""});

    const fetchHash = useCallback(async () => {
        setHash({questionList: "sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq"});
    }, []);

    const fetchQuestionLists = useCallback(async () => {
        console.log("fetching new question lists");
        const response: ApiResponse | boolean = await getQuestionLists(user?.token);

        if (typeof response !== "boolean" && response.data) {
            setQuestionLists(response.data);
        }
    }, [hash]);

    useEffect(() => {    
        fetchHash();
        fetchQuestionLists();
    }, []);

    const update = useCallback((newHash: Hash) => {
        console.log("called update");

        let shouldUpdate = false;
        let originalHash = { ...hash };
        let updatedHash = { ...newHash };

        console.log("new:    ", newHash);
        console.log("stored: ", originalHash);

        if (hash.questionList !== newHash.questionList) {
            console.log("was not equal");
            updatedHash = { ...updatedHash, questionList: newHash.questionList} 
            shouldUpdate = true;
        }

        if (shouldUpdate) {
            console.log("trying to set new hash: ", updatedHash);
            setHash(updatedHash);
            fetchQuestionLists();
        }
    }, [hash]);

    /*useEffect(() => {    
        socket?.on('aHash', (fetchedHash) => update(fetchedHash));
    }, []);*/

    useEffect(() => {    
        setInterval(() => {
            update({questionList: "sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq"});
        }, 15000)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            ... Things here later ...
        </>
    );
};

export default Admin;
```

After the initial render, and waiting two interval cycles, this is what I see in the console:

```
fetching new question lists
called update
new:  {questionList: 'sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq'}
stored:  {questionList: ''}
was not equal
trying to set new hash:  {questionList: 'sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq'}
fetching new question lists
called update
new:  {questionList: 'sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq'}
stored:  {questionList: ''}
was not equal
trying to set new hash:  {questionList: 'sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq'}
fetching new question lists
```

You can see that `stored` is empty. That leads me to believe that `setHash(updatedHash);` never runs for some reason. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having hacked about with this in codepen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/as-prop-base-forked-l3ncvo?file=/src/Application.tsx

This seems to me to be a closure issue as opposed to a React issue. If you have a look in the dev tools, you'll see the state of the component is doing what you're expecting it to. The issue is that the console log is not.

`useEffect` is only ever going to use an old version of `update`, so the console won't log what you're expecting. If you add `update` to the dependency array (and add a clean up so we don't end up with tonnes of intervals) you'll get what you're looking for. Can be seen in the linked codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in on this line :

```
socket?.on('aHash', (hash) => update(hash));
```

maybe when you register a listener, it keeps the first value of update only,

can you please share useSocket?

Comment: I have updated the question with my new tries

Answer (score 0):

```
    const [ hash, setHash ] = useState<Hash>({questionList: ""});

    const fetchHash = useCallback(async () => {
        setHash({questionList: "sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq"});
    }, []);
```

Include `setHash` in your dependency list et voilà

EDIT: Or well, you should include these dependencies in all your useCallback/useEffect hooks since the reference will be lost whenever the component updates. You always have to include all dependencies in the dependency list not to get unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

use setState(prevValue => {}) to get the the preferred effect. Also, if you running in a Strict mode this will fire the setState twice.

Here is how the code should look like:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

const Admin = () => {
    const [ questionLists, setQuestionLists ] = useState([]); 
    const [ hash, setHash ] = useState({questionList: ""});

    const fetchHash = useCallback(async () => {
        setHash({questionList: "sdhfubvwuedfhvfeuvyqhwvfeuq"});
    }, []);

    const fetchQuestionLists = useCallback(async () => {
        console.log("fetching new question lists");
        const response = {data: {hash: 'asdf-1234'}}

        setQuestionLists(response.data);
    }, [hash]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchHash();
        fetchQuestionLists();
    }, []);

    const update = (newHash) => {
        console.log("called update");

        setHash(oldHash => {
            console.log('old hash: ', oldHash);
            console.log('new hash', newHash);
            if (JSON.stringify(oldHash) !== JSON.stringify(newHash)) {
                return newHash
            }
        })
    };

    /*useEffect(() => {    
        socket?.on('aHash', (fetchedHash) => update(fetchedHash));
    }, []);*/

    useEffect(() => {    
        setInterval(() => {
            update({questionList: faker.random.numeric(36)});
        }, 15000)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Hash</h2>
            {JSON.stringify(hash)}
        </>
    );
};

export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases (socket & interval) the issue is that you need to re-define the callback functions with the new context of the variables in the scope, whenever something changes. In this case you will probably need to put "update" (and whatever other variable you need to "watch") inside the dependancy array of the useEffect.
Ive had a similar issues. Here is how I ended up defining socket callback that updates correctly. Notice that I added the save function (just a function that saves the state into the useState). Also, you need to return a clean up function to turn the socket callback off when the component unmounts. This way every time anything changes in the dependancy array, the hook re-runs and recreates that callback with the new information.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
socketRef?.current?.on(
  'private_message_sent_to_client',
  (data: IMessageResult) => {
    savePrivateMessages(data);
  }
);
return () => {
  socketRef?.current?.off('private_message_sent_to_client');
 };
}, [meta, selectedChatId, savePrivateMessages]);
```

And here is an example for you

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 socket?.on('aHash', (hash) => update(hash));
 return () => {
  socket?.off('aHash')
 };
}, [update, hash]);
```